# react native app change host port without ctrl m menu

Tags: react-native

The menu is not full. Its host & port settings page is missing. How can I set host & port without it? (android-windows).

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default android emulator?

Comment: yes. . .. . . .i was integrating react native into native android app

Comment: hmm maybe its a problem because you are integrating react-native to a android native app so using cntrl+m is toggling the native app dialog/menu and not the react-native debugger menu. Maybe try the following create a debug apk or simply run the app on a real device for example connect your android phone and run the app there. Then when running on your phone shake the phone and the react native dev menu should show up

Comment: menu shows up , but dev settings is missing its a different thing shows up

Comment: okay thats strange... i have no more ideas